# MenuItem under ContextMenu is not getting binded to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

I've two MenuItems which I placed as a part of Context Menu of one Menu Item. I'm able to bind the DataContext of parent Menu Item, but somehow I'm not able to bind the child MenuItems with the DataCOntext of the parent MenuItem.  Following is the code snippet.

```
    <MenuItem Name="miCommunityHealthIssues" Margin="3,3,3,6" Click="miCommunityHealthIssues_Click" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Style="{StaticResource ShowMenuItemFilterStyle}">
                        <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"> 
                                <MenuItem Name="miShowComhealthIssues" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IncludeCommunityRecords}" Checked="MenuItem_Checked" Unchecked="MenuItem_Unchecked"/>
                                <MenuItem Name="miShowSupComhealthIssues" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IncludeSuppressedCommunityRecords}" Checked="miShowSupComhealthIssues_Checked" Unchecked="miShowSupComhealthIssues_Unchecked"/>                                    
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
                    </MenuItem>
```

Please help me with code snippet rather than guiding me to another links. I've already referred lots of links and couldn't able to reach to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of the issue is in the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu`. When I attempt to recreate your code, I'm unable to specify `Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext` in the binding.

If you're simply trying to reference the parent `MenuItem`'s `DataContext`, I'd suggest *not* defining the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu`. The parent `MenuItem`'s `DataContext` will apply to all children elements, including the child `MenuItem`s:

```
<MenuItem Name="miCommunityHealthIssues" Margin="3,3,3,6" Click="miCommunityHealthIssues_Click" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Style="{StaticResource ShowMenuItemFilterStyle}">
    <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
        <!-- no datacontext definition necessary -->
        <ContextMenu> 
            <MenuItem Name="miShowComhealthIssues" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IncludeCommunityRecords}" Checked="MenuItem_Checked" Unchecked="MenuItem_Unchecked"/>
            <MenuItem Name="miShowSupComhealthIssues" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IncludeSuppressedCommunityRecords}" Checked="miShowSupComhealthIssues_Checked" Unchecked="miShowSupComhealthIssues_Unchecked"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is not working. Thank you for looking into this. There is something very minor I'm missing which is preventing me to reach to the solution. Did you tested this code? If it is working in your environment, then I wonder what failing in mine. Please let me know if you have anything more to share.